# CiviCRM upgrade issue 5.67.0

Tags: upgrade

DB error when upgrading Civi from 5.60.0 to 5.67.0

```
Type    DB_Error
Code    -3
Message DB Error: constraint violation
Mode    16
UserInfo    ALTER TABLE `civicrm_activity` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_activity_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_activity` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`d9_civicrm`.`#sql-48a_21833f`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_activity_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_activity` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL)]
DebugInfo   ALTER TABLE `civicrm_activity` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_activity_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_activity` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`d9_civicrm`.`#sql-48a_21833f`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_activity_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_activity` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like civicrm_activity.parent_id is pointing to orphan records. You will need to fix the orphan records and then run the upgrade. You can use [MySQL commands](https://gist.github.com/pradpnayak/6631f3c1bcafe0899432ea89206826af) to fix the records.